# No resource or method named 'common_tmp_dir' for 'Chef::Recipe ""init"'

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am getting the below error:

No resource or method named 'common_tmp_dir' for 'Chef::Recipe ""init"

my recipe has the following:

```
install_home        =   "/m1/common"
user            =   "syun"
group           =   "dba"
common_tmp_dir "Creating install home: #{install_home}" do
  path install_home
  user user
  group group
  action :create
end
```

please help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [directory](https://docs.chef.io/resource_directory.html) resource to create a new directory.

```
  directory "Creating install home: #{install_home}" do
    path install_home
    user user
    group group
    action :create
  end
```

Comment: is there a way to include the comment "Creating install home: #{install_home}" as part of this. Thanks

Comment: You can just add `log "Updating creating install_home"` before this.

Comment: @garnertb and @User3, I added an update that shows how to get the logging info you want.  Hopefully it is approved. But if not, the basic point is you can use any name you want for the resource, including "Creating install home: #{install_home}".  You then just need to add a `path` attribute to point to the directory's path.

Comment: I do have another recipe where I have the below which is working. cookbook_common_tmp_dir "Creating temporary folder: #{tmp_dir}" do
  path tmp_dir
  user user
  group group
  action :create
end
How? and in another place it is not & I have to use the directory resource. I am trying to understand if I have to register the method somewhere.